# asp.net-core 2.0 Docker deploy

Tags: docker, deployment, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an app developed in `asp.net-core 2.0` and deployed on Linux with `Docker`.

So I created Docker image and run it on Linux server like:

```
docker run -p 80:80 --name my-container my-image:1.0
```

So from Docker image `my-image:1.0` created container `my-container`

Now the issue is when I make some changes to my app and want to deploy that changes I have to stop/remove `my-container` and create a new one from new Docker image like:

```
docker stop my-container
docker rm my-container
docker run -p 80:80 --name my-container my-image:1.1
```

Is there any way to just update the container with the new image? Point is to use existing container with the new version of the image.

Comment: Considering the immutable nature of Docker images and containers, the answer will be no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to just update the container with the new image?

No. **But this is not what you need**, since you said that your goal is the following one:

> Now the issue is when I make some changes to my app and want to deploy that changes I have to stop/remove my-container and create a new one from new Docker image

Your Dockerfile looks certainly like that:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

So, you just need to create a volume to export your workdir `/app` into the host filesystem, outside the container (use `-v` parameter with `docker run`). Then simply restart the container after having applied changes to your app.